# Making a tableau extract in to marimekko chart

Tags: sql, extract, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau 8.2, and I'm trying to make a tableau extract into a marimekko chart.

I looked it up online, and the consensus is to use custom SQL to do this, but it looks like this is for earlier versions of Tableau, and in 8.2 I have to use legacy connection to do this. Only problem is, I can select an excel file and get the legacy connection option that leads me to the custom SQL option, but when I try to use legacy connection on a tableau extract, the option doesn't even pop up. So I'm wondering if I have to convert the tableau extract into an excel in order to get the option of legacy connection and then custom SQL or if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, unfortunately you can't perform a custom SQL (or even join 2 tables) on tdes. I don't know exactly how you're building your marimekko chart, but if it requires some calculation Tableau can't directly perform, then I suggest you to create a spreadsheet, drag all the fields you want to Detail (and choose bar chart, this way no time will be wasted generating a visualization) and export the table to a .mdb file (or Excel, your choice). Then connect to it and use your custom SQL.

Comment: But if you show us how your db looks like, and exactly what your marimekko dimensions are, we can try to figure out some way to perform the calculations in Tableau